# 'Recent Achievements' doesn't show new badges, privileges or reputation

Tags: bug, achievements-dialog

Today I earned two badges, privileges (don't know one or more) and reputation but `Recent Achievements` has stopped notifying me about this.

In my `Recent Achievements` tab it just shows that I earned 30 reputation today, but the rep I earned by editing answers it not visible with that. And my earned badges and privileges are also not visible.

Can somebody explain why this happens? Is there any change I need to make in settings (btw I don't think there is any setting option on SO)?

Comment: Caching maybe? :/

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you want to say. @DavidPostill

Comment: @David no. He's talking about the badges, not the reputation. It's not a dupe.

Comment: [Which badges do not cause a notification for experienced users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138113)

Comment: @DavidPostill I didn't receive a notification for `Custodian` badge. And I just reached at rep 500 but didn't receive the privileges notification.

Answer (score 2):

The reputation is showing only 30 because you clicked it at some point between February 13 and today, thus "clearing" it.

As for badges, both are Custodian which is not triggering a message for Veteran Users i.e. users with 200 reputation on at least one site, as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148599/152859).

List of badges that you should be notified about can be seen [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138391/152859).

Comment: and why I'm not receiving notification for privileges I received by reaching at 500 rep?

Comment: @Apurva [same reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151679/152859). :)